# How to overwrite exit event when using PyQGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I'm developing a plug-in using PyQGIS and when I click on the exit button the QGIS executes some code defined by itself (it asks if I want to save the changes and then exit). I'd like to overwrite this executing a code defined by me, but I can't find how to do it. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

ah which of these cases do you refer to

1.- you have a graphic interface, any QWidget and you click close

2.- you mean you close the QGis project

**For the first case**, it's simple, QWidgets have their own method so you simply rewrite it.
Of course, check that in your class that inherits from QWidget or the one you are using, you initialize the parent class with `super().__init__()`.
For example I am using this method for a QGis interface:

```
def closeEvent(self, event):
        for i in self.listCR:
            i.nameChanged.disconnect
        self.desconecPry()
```

**The second case**, we can also handle it, when someone opens a new project or another project, without closing QGis, our interface would remain open.
For this you can use the `cleared` signal of `QgsProject`, you also have the `projectSaved()` signal when the user during the execution clicks on save.

Comment: Thank you so much, it  was the second case for me. One thing though, when I click on the exit button, QGIS asks me if I want to save changes, do you know how to disable it? I've tried QgsProject.instance().setDirty(False) but it keeps asking if I want to save my changes.

Answer (score 2):

You can connect your function to the `aboutToClose` Signal of your `QgsApplication`, for example write a text file with 'QGIS closed!' to some temporary folder:

```
def test():
    f = open(r'/home/me/tmp/closed.txt', 'w')
    f.write('QGIS closed!')
    f.close()
    
QgsApplication.instance().aboutToQuit.connect(test)
```